# Higher order function, Flow type annotations

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm trying to write some very simple, functional examples to evaluate the Flow type system. Am I missing something obvious, or should this sample work:

```
function logger (message: string): void {
    console.log(message);
}

function consumer (logFunc: logger) {
    logFunc('foo');
}

consumer(logger);
```

When I try it on [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAGzgczQUwE6IBQC2mAzsQIZYBcixU2MYaAlNQG5wwAmiA3gFCJBiCAmJxkmAHSo0hEuSxMA3HwC+fPqEiwEw0SCK48MgGLgI1GVmxNeAoafN4A5MDhxnytRpFhiBnGN0a2UgA) I get "Callable signature not found in prototype". I'm getting the same message when run locally (flow 0.21.0):

```
  8:     logFunc('foo');
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function call. Callable signature not found in
  8:     logFunc('foo');
         ^^^^^^^ prototype
```

I can solve the problem by declaring a type alias explicitly, but that seems like unnecessary duplication (especially for more complex modules):

```
type loggerType = (message: string) => void;

function logger (message: string): void {
    console.log(message);
}

function consumer (logFunc: loggerType) {
    logFunc('foo');
}

consumer(logger);
```

The only relevant documentation I've found so far is: http://flowtype.org/docs/functions.html#function-based-type-annotations

Imagine that `consumer` and `logger` are separate modules (perhaps even in separate npm packages) and are more complicated, and `logger` is imported (es6, or commonJS).

- It doesn't seem reasonable to write the types twice (`logger` and `loggerType`).
- It also doesn't seem reasonable to repeat the type signature of `logger` in the `consumer` function - I want the type of the `logFunc` argument to exactly match the function called `logger`. Especially, repeating the types would be tedious for more complex functions.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this without explicitly repeating the type annotations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `typeof`:

```
function consumer (logFunc: typeof logger) {
    logFunc('foo');
}
```

Seems like a Flow bug that using an expression in a type position doesn't give you a meaningful error, but I'm not as familiar with it so maybe it means something else.

The error experience here is pretty confusing, though -- you may be better off with a type alias. Certainly in this snippet I would prefer an error on line 15 rather than on 1 and 9

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had completely overlooked the `typeof` keyword actually. Must've gone blind after looking for so long. The more you learn! Yeah the error messages aren't always the best, unfortunately.

Comment: When used in a type position, a function name refers to the function's prototype. This is to support pre-ES6 style classes.